# Converting mp3 to hls with gstreamer

Tags: python, audio, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I’m trying to convert a set of mp3s that represent chapters of an audiobook into HLS as part of a real-time streaming solution using gstreamer. While I have the code working, the main issue is that the conversion only creates one large segment per input file even if I specify 10 or 20 second segments in **hlssink**. Note that I'm doing this in-memory as bitstream chunks by downloading mp3 and mp4s from an application that stores the AV assets and that code is working fine for audio and video. Perhaps, I have to use another element such as **splitmuxsink** to manually split the files? I don’t have this problem with video. Here is the Python code fragment of my pipeline:

```
# Create the source element
    src = Gst.ElementFactory.make('appsrc', 'source')

    # Create the rest of the audio pipeline
    decodebin = Gst.ElementFactory.make('decodebin')
    audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make('audioconvert')
    avenc_aac = Gst.ElementFactory.make('avenc_aac')  
    mpegtsmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('mpegtsmux')
    hlssink = Gst.ElementFactory.make('hlssink')

    # Create the queue element
    queue = Gst.ElementFactory.make('queue')

    # Set the target-duration property of hlssink
    hlssink.set_property('target-duration', 20)  # Set target duration to 20 seconds

    # Set the location and playlist-location properties of hlssink
    hlssink.set_property('location', f'segment{i:05d}.ts')
    hlssink.set_property('playlist-location', f'playlist{i}.m3u8')
```

The main issue is that the conversion only creates one large segment per input file even if I specify 10 or 20 second segments in **hlssink**. Basically, it ignores the hlssink settings.

Comment: For the benefit of others, I found that this pipeline works well for this scenario:
gst-launch-1.0 -e filesrc location=input.mp3 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! avenc_aac ! aacparse ! queue ! hlssink2 max-files=0 playlist-length=0 playlist-root=./ location=./segment%05d.ts playlist-location=./playlist.m3u8